# React website refresh showing page not found

Tags: reactjs, routes, hosting

I have a build a React website and hosted in Hosting er. When i go to website and open another page and refresh, it's showing "Oops, looks like the page is lost." How i will resolve this bug? Is this problem with routing in React?

I need fully functional website like when i run in my system. But when hosted the pages are not working properly.

Comment: url rewrite in the concept you want to look into

Check this link to understand
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452840/react-router-throwing-404-upon-page-refresh-with-react-app-hosted-on-godaddy

Answer (score 1):

The reason the website shows `404` is because in react all routes go to the index.html to render the components. But in a standard hosting it will look for a HTML file in the route's directory which doesn't exist in a React Application. Hence we configure our hosting service to redirect all request to the root `index.html`.

In your case since you have hosted on Hostinger you may use  the follwoing guidelines to make updates to your `.htaccess`.

Official Guidelines from Hostinger:

https://www.hostinger.in/tutorials/what-is-react#How_to_Deploy_a_React_Application_on_Hostinger