# Relative Paths not working on vite react app in Plesk

Tags: reactjs, url, vite, plesk

I just deployed my vite react app in a Plesk domain. The problem is that if I access `www.mywebsite.com` it redirects me to `www.mywebsite.com/login`, which is fine, but if I try to access `www.mywebsite.com/login` directly, it will show the error "*We're sorry, but something went wrong.*". It happens with every other relative path, like `/users`, for example.

I'm sure it is basic knowledge, but I cannot seem to find an answer.

I think it requires some `htaccess` file or `web.config` file, but I don't know how they work, and I might be wrong.

EDIT:

So I managed to solve it by adding a .htaccess file to my dist folder with the following code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router throwing 404 upon page refresh with React app hosted on GoDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452840/react-router-throwing-404-upon-page-refresh-with-react-app-hosted-on-godaddy)

Comment: ... and more generally [React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928372/283366)

Comment: @Phil It kind of did, but not in the way I wanted. Using the HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter solves my problem, but adds `/#/` to all of the urls, which it's not my ideal solution. I'm still fighting with all other responses, as `web.config` files don't seem to work. Thank you! I'll update this once I found the solution I'm looking for :)

Comment: A `BrowserRouter` solution depends on the type of web server in use. For Apache it's via `RewriteRule`, for nginx it's `try_files`, etc